# Selenium: optimization of elements defining (Page Object)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have, e.g. "SignUp Page" as one of page objects to be implemented:

```
public class SignUpPage {

    WebDriver driver;
    public SignUpPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
}
```

I want to add(find) elements from this page(using @FindBy), which will be used in further methods:

```
public class SignUpPage {

       WebDriver driver;
       public SignUpPage(WebDriver driver) {
            this.driver = driver;
            PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
       }

       @FindBy (id = "register-email")
       private WebElement emailField;
       @FindBy (id = "register-confirm-email")
       private WebElement confirmEmailField;
       @FindBy (id = "register-password")
       private WebElement passwordField;

       public SignUpPage typeEmail(String email) {
           emailField.sendKeys(email);
           return this;
       }

       public SignUpPage typeConfirmEmail(String email) {
           confirmEmailField.sendKeys(email);
           return this;
       }
}
```

Is there any better way of organizing that @FindBy annotation? e.g. not to repeat it so many times, as so many elements we have.

Comment: thanks for all recommendations given below, guys. I will try all in working order, and will choose answer.

Comment: The way you did this is absolutely fine. You do need to define each element as each one has unique id/selector/whatever you choose to find it by. The only way to do less repeating is if you reuse the same elements in different classes. In such case you can store them in a parent class or some static class.

Comment: @Dmitry This is a simple framework which I have used for 'boxing' in multiple but similar elements into one variable - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47195901/can-i-organize-objects-in-page-object-model-with-arrays-or-hash-maps/47249652#47249652.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to break up the pages into different objects so that you can re-use some of the elements on other pages.

If you look at your SignUpPage it probably consists of these elements:
- Navbar
- Sign-up form
- Footer

If you look at your landing page, it probably also has a navbar and footer

If you make a separate class for each of these elements, you can add these elements as part of each page as an "has-a" relation ship

```
public class SignUpPage {
    public SignUpForm signUpForm;
    public NavBar navBar;
    public Footer footer;
    private WebDriver driver;

    public SignUpPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        signUpForm = new SignUpForm(driver);
        navbar = new NavBar(driver);
        footer = new Footer(driver)
    }
}


public class SignUpForm {

      WebDriver driver;
      public SignUpForm(WebDriver driver) {
            this.driver = driver;
            PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
      }

      @FindBy (id = "register-email")
      private WebElement emailField;
      @FindBy (id = "register-confirm-email")
      private WebElement confirmEmailField;
      @FindBy (id = "register-password")
      private WebElement passwordField;

      public SignUpPage typeEmail(String email) {
          emailField.sendKeys(email);
          return this;
      }

      public SignUpPage typeConfirmEmail(String email) {
          confirmEmailField.sendKeys(email);
          return this;
      }
}

public class NavBar {

      WebDriver driver;
      public NavBar(WebDriver driver) {
            this.driver = driver;
            PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
      }

      @FindBy (id = "menu")
      private WebElement menu;
}

public class Footer {

      WebDriver driver;
      public Footer(WebDriver driver) {
            this.driver = driver;
            PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
      }

      @FindBy (id = "contactList")
      private WebElement contactList;
}
```

If you add methods like `Login(String mail, String password)` to the `NavBar` class you can call it from every page that has a `NavBar` using Something like

```
LandingPage.NavBar.Login("me@xyz.com", "s3cr3t");
// Or
LandingPage.NavBar.GoToSignUpPage().SignUp("me@xyz.com", "s3cr3t");
```

In the last example, the `SignUpPage` **has a** `SignUpForm` which is used when calling `SignUp`

Answer (score 0):

when we have more than a single criteria to identify one or more WebElement objects, you can make use of one of the following

**@FindBys**

```
@FindBys({
  @FindBy(id = "register-email")
  @FindBy(id = "register-confirm-email")
  @FindBy(id = "register-password")
})

private List<WebElement> elementsWithBoth_EmailANDPassword;
```

**@FindAll :**

```
@FindAll({
   @FindBy(id = "register-email")
   @FindBy(id = "register-confirm-email")
   @FindBy(id = "register-password")
})

private List<WebElement> elementsWithBoth_EmailANDPassword
```

check this [link](http://startingwithseleniumwebdriver.blogspot.in/2015/04/different-type-of-annotation-in-page.html). Hope this helps.

Comment: FindBys uses chaining. So in the example it will find "register-password" element inside "register-confirm-email" element which will be inside "register-email" element and so on and on and on... Also with FindAll it will return a list of webelement with no way of differentiating between the elements. So if I base the pageobject code on the order of elements returned and the user interface changes, pageobject will need to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

As you are implementing **`PageFactory`** through **`POM`**, so in each **`Page Object`** you need to define each `WebElement` with whom you want to interact within the **`Page Object`** just like the way we do **`driver.findElement()`** and **`driver.findElements()`** repeatedly in normal circumstances.

So you are on track regarding the above point.

Having said that there are still some flaws in your code block as follows :

- **`SignUpPage`** : The **`constructor`** of the Page Object Class i.e. **`public class SignUpPage {}`** shouldn't be used to initialize the `Page Object` as such. Logically, the **`constructor`** of the Page Object Class is invoked automatically when **`PageFactory.initElements()`** is called out. So ideally the constructor will look like :

  ```
  WebDriver driver;

  //constructor
  public SignUpPage(WebDriver driver)
  {
      this.driver=driver;
  }
  ```
- **`PageFactory.initElements(driver, this)`** : The initialization of the `Page Object` must be controlled from your `Test Class` (possibly under **`@Test`** Annotation), where you can load any `Page Object` as per your `Test Case` requirement at runtime as follows :

  ```
  @Test (priority=0)
  public void checkSignUp()
  {
      //Initialize the Page Object - SignUpPage.class
      SignUpPage sign_up_page = PageFactory.initElements(driver, SignUpPage.class);

      //Call the method - typeEmail(String email) within SignUpPage.class
      sign_up_page.typeEmail("Dmitry");
  }
  ```

Comment: hi @DebanjanB. Hm... I thought to move init to separate class, smth like "Base Page", in which we returning "return PageFactory.initElements(driver, pageClass)", and extend that BasePage from every page.  Can You please explain, why init it in every test is better, than one time declaring in e.g. BasePage, and further extending?

Comment: Why again a separate `Base Page`? There should be distinct modules for different functions. In general 4 basic functions can be distributed in 4 modules e.g.  `Test Class`, `Browser Factory`, `Page Objects` and `Assertions` where your `Page Objects` module will contain all the Page Objects. The call out to initialize the `Page Objects` will be handled from `Test Class`. Let us keep the structure simple.

Comment: `"return PageFactory.initElements(driver, pageClass)"` is not a best of the ideas as **Method Chaining** often pushes us to **StaleElementReferenceException**

Comment: I don't agree that calling `PageFactory.initElements` outside the constructor is a bad practice in this context. This way you get a ready to use PageObject. In your example, the constructor does not even gets called as you don't create a `SignUp` page.

Comment: @EugeneS Did you find `PageFactory.initElements outside the constructor is a bad practice` within the context of my `Answer`? Perhaps, you saw it right, `the constructor does not even gets called as you don't create a SignUp page`. I would load a `single page object` at a time as per my need and attain the **best performance** in terms of **`Test Execution`**.

Comment: @EugeneS `Performance Aspects` are clearly out of scope for `this.QA`. Can you raise a new question for the SO volunteers to Answer?

Comment: An object of the PageObject is only created automatically (ie constructor called by reflection) when the initElements(driver, class) method is used and then the appropriate fields are proxied. When the initElements(driver, this) method is called and the existing object passed in 'this' is proxied. Prefer the one with the initElements(driver, this) call inside the constructor as it clearly defines how the object fields are being proxied in one place. Also if one wants to use a custom ElementLocatorFactory and\or FieldDecorator then it can be hidden  from the test code.Just my preference though.

Comment: @Grasshopper I have answered my stand on the first part i.e. from where & how to call `init()`. I think by ElementLocatorFactory you are pointing to the same PageObject only. Am I missing something?

Comment: I just mentioned that whichever method of initElements() one uses an object is created or already exists, so a constructor is always called. Though I am not sure I fully understand your query - 'ElementLocatorFactory you are pointing to the same PageObject only.' But the different overloaded methods of initElements() currently only support custom elementfactory and decorator for existing pageobject objects.